# σ-algebra satisfying the given conditions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces

This is the problem:

> Let $X\neq\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{V}$ a vector space of bounded real functions with X as domain, satisfying
>
> 1. The function identically 1 belongs to $\mathcal{V}$
> 2. If $f,g \in \mathcal{V}$ then the function $x\mapsto \max\{f(x),g(x)\} \in \mathcal{V}$
> 3. If $(f_n)_n \subset \mathcal{V}$ is an increasing sequence and uniformly bounded, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n \in \mathcal{V}$

Prove that exists a $\sigma\text{-algebra } \mathcal{F}$ over $X$ such that $\mathcal{V}$ coincides with the $\mathcal{F}$-measurable bounded functions.

> Now, let $T:\mathcal{V}\to\mathbb{R}$ a linear transformation such that
>
> 1. $Tf\geq 0$ for $f\in\mathcal{V}$, $f\geq 0$
> 2. For all $(f_n)_n\subset\mathcal{V}$ such that $f_n\geq 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}Tf_n=0$

Prove that exists a measure $\mu$ over $\mathcal{F}$ such that
$$Tf=\int_X f\,d\mu, \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{V}$$

The idea of taking the subsets whose indicator function lies in $\mathcal{V}$ worked and it was possible to find the measure. But I can't prove that every function in $\mathcal{V}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable... Can someone help me with this? I really don't know how to start with this part.

Comment: I currently have no time. The  Riesz Respresentation Theorem on P40 of Rudin's book 'Real and Complex Analysis(3rd)' may help you.

Comment: For your first question, try considering the sets whose indicator function lies in $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, it was very useful, but I have a problem with $\mathcal{V}\subset {\Mathcal{F}-measurable bounded functions}$. Is that true?